# How can I merge rows in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, merge

My Excel sheet contains columns for id, date, amount and name.
If two or more rows have the same id and name I want to merge them into one row with the amount of those two combined. Can anybody help me doing this?

Comment: You can either use a Pivot Table to summarize the data like this or you can use VBA to summarize the data. If you want to take the VBA route then we'd like to see (1) the corresponding tag in your question post and (2) the VBA code you have written thus far in order to attempt a solution in this respect. The latter of the two is mostly due to the fact that this site is **not** a free code-writing service. Yet, we strive to help fellow programmers write their own code.

Comment: @pnuts I just posted an answer for you. Let me know if this is what you've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation with Columns ID and NAME (=ID&NAME) in another column and look for the pivot table. Move to Insert->Pivot table option to get the attached answer]

Hope this clarifies

Comment: yes it works.. while cells are concatenated we can have a single name right.. Then by using the new column, we can find the sum value using the Pivot table.. I hope I am not wrong.  Hello Alexxx, are you looking after this as what I suggest

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (as far as I understand the problem) using a PivotTable:

[image]

As you can see, there is not really much to it. Just insert a pivot table and drag the ID & Name to the `Rows` while you move the dates and the values to the `Values` section of the pivot table. The `Values` in the `Column` section will be automatically generated.

The only thing I changed at the end was to format the pivot table nicely doing the following:

1. Remove SubTotals by name
2. Using a PivotTable style that I like from the PivotTable menu in the section `Design`.
3. Show items in a tabular format. That means that the name and the ID are shown on one row and not in a cascading format (ID in one row and the name in a second row underneath + indented). You can achieve this by right-clicking on the name and selecting `Field Settings`. A new window opens (showing the settings). Go here to the `Layout & Print` tab and select `Show item labels in a tabular form`. You might have to repeat that for the field `Name` **and** the field `ID` (depending on which of the two fields you chose to show first in the `Rows` section of the PivotTable).

Let me know if this solved your problem or if you have any questions.

<sub>Note: since no sample data has been provided I made some up. I sure hope this data is somewhat similar to what you are trying to aggregate.</sub>

**Used sample data:**

```
ID  Date        Amount  Name
1   05.03.2015  121     Peter
2   14.01.2015  127     Max
3   11.01.2015  77      Eva
4   06.11.2015  141     Jamie
5   04.03.2015  58      Sophie
1   04.04.2015  94      Peter
7   20.06.2015  52      Lucas
3   14.12.2015  136     Eva
2   02.11.2015  93      Max
10  20.08.2015  59      Mason
4   11.01.2015  145     Jamie
4   02.02.2015  113     Jamie
4   26.02.2016  89      Jamie
1   30.03.2016  137     Peter
15  09.09.2015  81      Jackson
16  25.02.2015  61      Liam
2   26.02.2016  133     Max
2   26.10.2015  80      Max
19  25.09.2015  76      Aiden
```